# Abstraction and Convolution - When to Make Things Not-so-Obvious in Order to Increase Efficiency

Tags: c#, optimization, memory-management

I'm in the processes of designing a class `Word`, which represents a word in a dictionary (French). I'll use a simple number to represent the number of words in standard French, for the sake of easy math: **50,000**.

Now, I'm trying to determine whether or not abstracting/convoluting the class in order to be more memory (and maybe even time) efficient is really a good idea. This is the structure that I currently have:

```
class Word
{
    public string word { get; set; }
    public bool aspirate { get; set; }
    public List<GrammaticalForms> forms { get; set; }

    struct GrammaticalForms
    {
        public string form { get; set; }
        public string definition { get; set; }
    }
    public NounForms nounForms { get; set; }
    public AdjectiveForms adjectiveForms { get; set; }
    public VerbForms verbForms { get; set; }
}

class NounForms
{
    public string gender { get; set; }
    public string masculinSingular { get; set; }
    public string femininSingular { get; set; }
    public string masculinPlural { get; set; }
    public string femininPlural { get; set; }
}

class AdjectiveForms
{
    public string masculinSingular { get; set; }
    public string femininSingular { get; set; }
    public string masculinPlural { get; set; }
    public string femininPlural { get; set; }
    public string nonAspirate { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
}
```

I won't include `VerbForms` because it's currently a huge amount of code, and I'm still looking for a better way to design it. The problem will be evident from looking at a few example changes that I could make to these 3 classes though.

---

Currently I'm primarily using `string` to hold the data. Most of them cannot be changed, because they will actually hold strings. Others though, such as `gender` (`NounForms`) and `location` (`AdjectiveForms`) *can be*.

What do I mean by *changed*? Considering that in memory, there will be approximately **50,000 - 100,000** instantiations of the `Word` class in memory when the application is running. If I were, for example, make the following two changes to the design:

`gender` (was `string`) --> `char`

`location` (was `string`) --> `char`

I could use `m` (masculin), `f` (feminin), and `b` (both) in `gender` of `NounForms` as one-character short-handed notation, in order to save memory. I could use `a` (after), `b` (before), `n` (neutral) in `location` of `AdjectiveForms`, to accomplish the same goal.

When using that data, I would simply need to remember the one-character identifiers for the real *meaning* of the data, instead of just *having the value on-hand as a `string`* (which is easier to deal with).

If we assume that we have **10,000** `NounForms` and **10,000** `AdjectiveForms` in memory, the difference adds up quickly,:

**20,000** `string`, approximately 30 bytes each (18 [empty] + ~12 bytes of character data) = **600,000** bytes;

**20,000** `char`, 2 bytes each (unicode) = **40,000** bytes.

That's a factor of 15, ~ **.5 megabytes less with the character version**.

---

So here's the question: are optimizations like this ***standard***? I mean to say, it becomes a little bit more difficult to maintain the code because it's not *inherently obvious* (at least to me), so are these optimizations a good idea in general?

I can think of several other places where I could optimize, such as `pronominalForm` of `VerbForms`. Currently I am using a `string` to represent the *full form* of the pronominal verb, whereas I could just as easily use a `bool` to say "*does* it have a pronominal form?", and then write an algorithm to conjugate the pronominal form when it is necessary. Example:

`faire` ("to do") --> `pronominalForm` = true --> `se faire` (pronominal)

... algorithm ... add "se " to the beginning if the first letter of the verb is a consonant, otherwise add "s'" (`expliquer` ["to explain"] --> `s'expliquer`.

To me the optimizations seem like a good idea, but are the little abstractions bad for maintainability or readability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `enum` to describe gender/form instead of `string` or `char`. You can use `byte` as `enum` base so should be as memory-efficient as `char` but you gain safety that only certain values will be stored.
2. If you can easily write an algorithm to transform word to it's *full form* I would go with `bool` version.
3. I'm not an expert, but I think they are ways to describe word variations without actually writing the entire variation. Did you consider storing that information instead of every version of the word?

Comment: I was thinking about an `Enum`, kind of like a symbol table - I'll probably end up using that. As for the conjugations of nouns, adjectives and verbs, *yes* there are ways to conjugate them with an algorithm, which I will write in order to populate the XML I use as the dictionary, instead of writing it all out by hand. The problem with not having them in-memory is that for the purpose of the application as a whole, it's *necessary* to have them all in memory. It's a linguistic analyzer - there are several words (even in English) that have the same conjugation but mean two different things.

Comment: For example: `suis` -> ('être', IndPreFPS)   // First person singular, present, indicative of the verb 'être' -- ('suivre', IndPreFPS) // First person singular, present, indicative of the verb 'suivre' -- ('suivre', IndPreSPS) // Second person singular, present, indicative of the verb 'suivre' -- ('suivre', ImpPreSPS)  // Second person singular, present, imperative of the verb 'suivre'. Taken directly from a comment in my code. In order to significantly reduce the complexity of the "analysis" stage, having them all in memory makes determining the *origin/meaning* of the word much easier.